# CSS - under 991px radio buttons still selecting hidden div

Tags: css, media-queries

I have different version of a form using radio buttons depending on the viewport.  I have put my code below but, when the browser resizes to show the smaller forms for mobile the radio buttons are selecting the radio buttons in the hidden divs for the larger viewports..  how can i get around this please?

```
    <style>
    
    @media screen and (min-width: 992px)
{
    .product-under-991px
    {
        display: none;
        visibility: hidden;
        content-visibility: hidden;
    }
    .product-under-768px
    {
        display: none;
        visibility: hidden;
        content-visibility: hidden;
    }   
}

    @media screen and (max-width: 991px) and (min-width: 768px)
{
    .product-over-992px 
    {
        display: none;
        visibility: hidden;
        content-visibility: hidden;
    }
    .product-under-768px
    {
        display: none;
        visibility: hidden;
        content-visibility: hidden;
    }   
}
    
    @media screen and (max-width: 767px)
{
    .product-over-992px 
    {
        display: none;
        visibility: hidden;
        content-visibility: hidden;
    }
    .product-under-991px
    {
        display: none;
        visibility: hidden;
        content-visibility: hidden;
    }   
}
    
</style>


<div class="product-over-992px">
    <?php include('shop-products-2021/shop-30ltr-sack-over-992px.php'); ?>
    <?php include('shop-products-2021/shop-60ltr-sack-over-992px.php'); ?>
    <?php include('shop-products-2021/shop-bulk-bag-over-992px.php'); ?>
    <?php include('shop-products-2021/shop-2-5-cubemet-over-992px.php'); ?>
</div>  <!--product-over-992px--> 


<div class="product-under-991px">
    <?php include('shop-products-2021/shop-30ltr-sack-under-991px.php'); ?> 
    <?php include('shop-products-2021/shop-60ltr-sack-under-991px.php'); ?>
    <?php include('shop-products-2021/shop-bulk-bag-under-991px.php'); ?>
    <?php include('shop-products-2021/shop-2-5-cubemet-under-991px.php'); ?>
</div>  <!--product-under-991px--> 


<div class="product-under-768px">
    <?php include('shop-products-2021/shop-30ltr-sack-under-768px.php'); ?> 
    <?php include('shop-products-2021/shop-60ltr-sack-under-768px.php'); ?> 
    <?php include('shop-products-2021/shop-bulk-bag-under-768px.php'); ?>
    <?php include('shop-products-2021/shop-2-5-cubemet-under-768px.php'); ?>
</div>  <!--product-under-768px-->
```

Comment: Can you make a working snippet because I don't know how you are implementing the radio buttons from the code you have given. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Hi thank you, this is the actual live URL, resizing the window to below 768px is where the radio buttons don't select but then resizing back up they are checked...
https://puckamuck.co.uk/order-puckamuck-dev.php